# Using Mongoose, how do I insert key value pairs as objects into an array via a form?

Tags: arrays, forms, node.js, express, mongoose

Consider the following simple schema:

```
var PostSchema = new Post({
  body : String,
  tags : []
}
```

Via a form POST (REST HTTP API that I'm developing), I would like to insert key/value pairs into the `tags` array so that the resulting mongodb document would look like:

```
{
  "body" : "This is the post body",
  "tags" : [
              {"Color" : "Orange"},
              {"Color" : "Blue"},
              {"Person" : "Ted"},
              {"Person" : "Fred"},
              {"Person" : "Joe"},
              {"Stone" : "Diamond"}
           ]
}
```

My question is, how do I name the form fields for `tags` to accomplish this? I was thinking something like `tags[0][color]` for each color, but that doesn't work, that creates a separate array for each key inside the tags array with a list of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of feel silly now. The solution is to (obviously) supply the `tags` like so:

```
tags[0][color] = orange
tags[1][color] = blue
tags[2][person] = ted
tags[3][person] = fred
tags[4][person] = joe
tags[5][stone] = diamond
```

My brain was stuck on grouping them all into `tags[0]` - not sure why.